# Can I have this cluster shape in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

Layered two rectangles like `Cluster1` or `Cluster2` in the following image:

[image: illustration of cluster shape]

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get without hassle is nested clusters, like so:

```
digraph N {
  rankdir=LR
  labelloc=b

  subgraph clusterA1 {  // outer cluster
    subgraph clusterA { // inner cluster
      graph [bgcolor=white]
      label=Cluster1
      Node1
    }
  }
  subgraph clusterB1 {
    subgraph clusterB {
      label=Cluster2
      Node2
    }
  }
  Node1 -> Node2 [minlen=2]
}
```

Giving:
[image]
It may be possible to get the look you are after by post-processing (with Python, gvpr, or the like) a similar input and creating or repositioning a cluster or node to give the look you want.  Not sure.

Comment: I was also thinking that: can we customize the cluster shape via image or anything else?

Comment: All the cluster attributes: https://graphviz.org/docs/clusters/  No image attribute, but maybe something with bgcolor or class